# Is it possible to get a hard reference to an object in a linkedlist?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Is it possible to store a "list item" in a java linkedlist? I know we can fetch a genric "element" but what I really want is some object where I can use next to view and manage linked list. For example:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
// add some data
Integer thirdInt = list.get(3);
ListItem third = list.getListItem(3);
```

// now I want to store this third, and maybe access its 'next' etc.
I know it will not be third always, but I care about the relative references. As in third, fifth, seventh, tenth etc. As long as they come in an order, it is ok.

Is this possible, or perhaps any other way to achieve this ..?

Answer (score 1):

The method `LinkedList::listIterator(int index)` returns an iterator into the `List` starting at the specified index. The returned `ListIterator` is an `Iterator` so you can call `next` to get the next element, plus it has additional methods such as `previous` and methods to enable modification of the list such as `add` to insert into the list at the current position.

Here is the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-).